# How Do I Temporarily Change the Display Language in a Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, language

I have been trying to assist a Japanese Windows user troubleshoot a networking issue and wanted to see the results of `ipconfig /all`.  However, when that user types this in a command prompt, the results come back in Japanese.  That, unfortunately, is not a language that I can read.  Short of resetting the locale for the entire system, is there a way to get English output in a single `cmd.exe` window?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to change the code page in that `cmd.exe` window with `chcp 437`.